# Can't find process using a quarter of memory

Tags: debian, memory, memory-usage

I am running a small vServer with Debian 9 (stretch) and 2GB RAM.

For a few months I am somehow missing about 500MB RAM and which I cannot find out how they are used.

When I run `free -h`

```
              total     used      free    shared  buff/cache     available
Mem:           2.0G     1.0G      482M       66M        511M     764M
Swap:          1.0G       0B      1.0G
```

I can see that half of the memory is used, about a quarter is used for caches that can be freed if it is needed and the rest is free.

But when I now check my running processes I can only find about 500MB are used by my processes.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                   
 1458 mysql     20   0  927516 359260      0 S   0.0 17.5 108:31.26 mysqld                                                                                                    
  877 seafile   20   0  258032  94644   4876 S   0.0  4.6   0:22.92 python2.7                                                                                                 
  460 seafile   20   0  237156  85504   8036 S   0.0  4.2   0:13.14 python2.7                                                                                                 
  463 seafile   20   0  233096  82236   8956 S   0.0  4.0   0:05.79 python2.7                                                                                                 
  875 seafile   20   0  244356  81644   5408 S   0.0  4.0   0:19.50 python2.7                                                                                                 
  461 seafile   20   0  232464  81032   8232 S   0.0  3.9   0:03.58 python2.7                                                                                                 
 4054 www-data  20   0  374264  54976  45128 S   0.0  2.7   0:07.58 php-fpm7.0                                                                                                
 4026 www-data  20   0  372652  54840  44408 S   0.0  2.7   0:10.36 php-fpm7.0                                                                                                
 1865 seafile   20   0 1704520  52828     16 S   0.0  2.6   3:45.10 seaf-server                                                                                               
 4021 www-data  20   0  370836  48880  40468 S   0.0  2.4   0:10.83 php-fpm7.0                                                                                                
 1975 seafile   20   0  129128  47156   1944 S   0.0  2.3   0:02.06 python2.7                                                                                                 
21106 netdata   20   0  189412  36600   2660 S   0.3  1.8  16:07.50 netdata                                                                                                   
 1604 lukas     20   0  107132  34860   2736 S   0.0  1.7   2:07.91 gunicorn
```

I have no clue where the remaining 500MB Memory are.

I suspected the kernel but running `slabtop` shows it uses only about 80MB.

```
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 76599.41K / 79594.40K (96.2%)
```

I am running [netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata) on my server, which shows a nice overview of the memory usage per category and indeed it shows my missing 530MB. I played around with the grouping and created a new group called `testing` with the following config and it includes my missing memory (in `/etc/netdata/apps_groups.conf`)

```
testing: systemd*
```

[image: Netdata]

Why does systemd (or something netdata categorizes as systemd) use about a quarter of my memory? After a reboot it uses only 50MB but after some time it always uses about 500MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd is the process with pid 1. All the other processes are children of systemd.

In netdata, all processes not matched by the groups given are assigned to category `other`.

Since netdata assigns processes to groups respecting their hierarchy, the match `systemd*` just moved most processes from `other` to `testing`. So `systemd*` is not a really useful match.

If I were you, I would attempt to understand which applications the server runs and add groups for these specific applications.

Additionally you can [enable the systemd charts in netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/monitoring-systemd-services). This will allow you see the `Services` section in netdata. Depending on the debian version, a reboot may be required to enable memory reporting for them (you may need to add a kernel boot parameter - check the wiki).

Comment: That really makes sense. In the meantime I noticed by chance that stoping Seafile solves it. Maybe it uses a lot of processes with little memory usage each. I’ll investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: You were right. I enabled the systemd charts and indeed seahub is at fault. I didn't notice it in htop as it is running many processes using about 80MB each.

Comment: nice! I am glad netdata helped.